# Change product in cart when billing country is changed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

We have continent specific products, the geoip is used to select the initial product to add but if the user changes the billing country (which triggers a change of currency) how can I hook into this action to modify the product in the cart?

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin/theme, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum, in this case: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce

Comment: It appears i have cock-all chance of getting a reply in either =)